# Calculations on Matrices

Tags: matrices

$A$ and $B$ are two matrices such that $AB=B$ and $BA=A$, then find the value of $${A^2} + {B^2}$$
I got no idea of how to proceed further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to simplify the expression, you get the following:

\begin{align*}
A^2 + B^2 &= BABA + ABAB \\
&= BBA + AAB \\
&= BA + AB \\
&= A + B
\end{align*}

Comment: Sorry, how did you end up with $A+B = I$?  If you plug that in to the expression $(A+B)(A+B - I)$, you get $A^2+B^2 = I(0) = 0 = I.$

Comment: I'm not too sure you can do that since you aren't guaranteed invertibility :)

Answer (score 0):

We can do better. According to Alvin's post, $(A+B)^2=A^2+B^2+AB+BA=2(A+B)$, that is $X(X-2I_n)=0$ where $X=A+B=A^2+B^2$. Finally, $X$ is diagonalizable and $X=Pdiag(2I_p,0_q)P^{-1}$ where $p+q=n$ and $P\in GL_n(K)$.